# center div within parent and auto size to text content

Tags: css, html, center

I am having trouble centering a div within its parent.  I'd also like to make the child div auto fit its text content with a background colour applied.  The child in question is #JoinSft-msg-block

here's my html:

```
  <div id="JoinSubfooter">
    <div id="JoinSubfooter-wrapper">
        <div id="subft-line"></div>
        <div id="JoinSft-msg-block">some text here</div>
    </div>
```

Here's my CSS

```
     #JoinSubfooter {
     width: 100%;
     height: 200px;
     background: transparent url(../images/grey_body_noise.png);
     clear: both;
     /*Clears all columns and sets the footer at the bottom*/
 }
 #JoinSubfooter-wrapper {
     width:981px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
 }
 #JoinSft-msg-block {
     display:inline-block;
     padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
     background-color:#333333;
     font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
     font-size:18px;
     color:#FFFFFF;
     margin: 0px auto;
 }
```

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FA5F7/1/)

Comment: For anoyone to play with http://jsfiddle.net/gQ48m/

Comment: Can you please explain your problem in brief

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using an inline-block element, you can just apply text-align center to its parent;

i.e.

```
 #JoinSubfooter-wrapper {
     text-align:center;
     width:981px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
 }
```

Comment: i plan to put some other cild divs with that parent.  Would that mean everything then becomes centered?

Comment: If they are display inline-block yes.

Comment: thank you.  is there another way of centering the child div with text-align: center while maintaining a block of background colour to the text?

Comment: Where do you plan on having your other child elements? These can be floated if you want them to be left or right. inline-block is the only way of wrapping the text with a background-color without setting a width. The other methods need a fixed width to be cross browser compatible.

Comment: two other divs will go benieth child but probably in the center, so I think your method is probably great for that?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this instead of `display:inline-block;` but not sure if it works in all browsers

```
display: table;
```